# Trigger cannot handle case sensitive values

Tags: apex, trigger, error

I have a trigger that populate Lookup Account Name field  with Text field(My Account Name) on Opportunity object. Trigger is working fine but there is a issue of Case Sensitivity.
For Example
My Account Name - shivani   (IF i TYPE THIS)
Account Nmae = shivani //already created with this name
Account Name -  shivani //trigger works

But,when I change the case of account name like this 'SHIVANI' or 'Shivani'
My Account Name - Shivani
Account Nmae = shivani //already created with this name
Account Name -           //trigger  DOES NOT works
error occurs

My question is how can i handle this case sensitive issue in triggers.

code for reference

```
Map<String,Opportunity> MapAccountName = new Map<String,Opportunity>();
    for(Opportunity opp: opptList){
        MapAccountName.put(opp.My_Account_Name__c,opp);
    }
    List<Account> accList = [SELECT id,Name from Account where Name
                            in:MapAccountName.keySet()];
    for(Account acc : accList){
        MapAccountName.get(acc.Name).AccountId = acc.ID;
       
    }
```

Comment: Don't add random tags to your questions. Tags are meant to describe what things the question is about to help people determine whether a question is relevent to them or within their knowledge set.

Comment: To add to the above, as this site is the ***Salesforce*** Stack Exchange, you do not need to add any tags to tell us your question is about the Salesforce platform, as that would be redundant.

Comment: Also, if you get an error, please include its message verbatim to reduce the amount of guesswork needed by the community to assist you.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear about what you are trying to do, what you've tried, and what actually happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom maps you write with a String key use *cAsE-sEnSiTiVe* strings, so you would want/need to convert to uppercase or lowercase when using the map:

```
Map<String,Opportunity> MapAccountName = new Map<String,Opportunity>();
for(Opportunity opp: opptList) {
    MapAccountName.put(opp.My_Account_Name__c?.toLowerCase(),opp);
}
List<Account> accList = [SELECT id,Name from Account where Name
                        in:MapAccountName.keySet()];
for(Account acc : accList){
    MapAccountName.get(acc.Name.toLowerCase()).AccountId = acc.ID;
}
```

As a practical matter, there might be more than one opportunity with the same account, so you should map the names to Id values:

```
Map<String,Id> MapAccountName = new Map<String,Id>();
for(Opportunity opp: opptList) {
    MapAccountName.put(opp.My_Account_Name__c?.toLowerCase(),null);
}
for(Account acc: [SELECT id,Name from Account where Name
                        in:MapAccountName.keySet()]) {
    MapAccountName.put(acc.Name.toLowerCase(), acc.Id);
}
for(Opportunity opp: opptList) {
    opp.AccountId = MapAccountName.get(opp.My_Account_Name__c?.toLowerCase());
}
```

I cover this in some detail in my [blog post](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html).